# Image Thumbnail Display in Drupal with Colorbox

Tags: drupal, colorbox

I'm not very familiar with Drupal and I was hoping for some guidance. I believe a module called "Colorbox" is what I'm working with here, but I'm not sure. I have views of different content types, basically they're all different kinds of pictures. (Portrait, Landscape, etc.) Each view/content-type has it's own page. In the Content Type>Manage Display section, I can set the format of the image to be "Colorbox" but instead of getting pages that look like this:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/029q86z2c

I get pages that look like this:

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c1q87363

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Content Type >> Manage Display setting is for "Node" settings. If what you have shown us is in fact a View (Embedded in a Node perhaps?) and not just Node output, then you need to adjust the settings in your View.

If it's a View, it looks like it's set to show a title instead of the actual image field but I can't be sure. You would also need to specify Colorbox settings and image settings as well in the specific View.

Can you confirm the screen capture you provided is of a View or simply Node output?

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes it was a setting in the View that needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider some options or check out some of the available tutorials:

- [Media Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) module
- [Colorbox for Drupal 7, part 3: Building a    image gallery and a
  image slideshow](http://vimeo.com/26411524)